# Creating Excel file: Xlsxwriter not defined

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am struggling with simply creating an Excel file using xlswriter with Python. I use Python 3.4, and xlswriter 0.6.3.

Here is what I get:

```
>>> import XlsxWriter

>>> workbook=xlsxwriter.Workbook('file.xlsx')

Traceback (most recent call last): File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    workbook=xlsxwriter.Workbook('file.xlsx')
NameError: name 'xlsxwriter' is not defined
```

I have tried with different spellings (capital or not), it makes no difference.

Comment: See the [example code](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_demo.html#ex-demo) - both occurrences should be all lowercase: `xlsxwriter`. I don't know what you're getting from `import XlsxWriter`, I would expect an error there.

Comment: Python is case sensitive. So you have imported  XlsxWriter uppercase  and while using xlsxwriter lower case.

Comment: After multiple attempts, I could not even import any pip... I think there have been a bug with pip installation... I have finally choosen Python 2.7, and it works well. Thank you for you answers!